# Ruby - Validates field presence after create

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it possible to validate a field for presence after the initial creation?
I want to make phone number mandatory if the user wants to update their account after signing up.

```
  validates :phone, presence: true, if: .....
```

if I use `on: :update` I can no longer authenticate until the field is filled

Comment: How does your authentication code looks like?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to accomplish this task assuming it is a normal Rails model backed by a DB table. Off the top of my head you can do:

```
validates :phone,
          presence: true,
          if: Proc.new{ |model| model.id.present? }
```

Or more to the point and doesn't fail if you assign an ID before saving:

```
validates :phone,
          presence: true,
          if: Proc.new{ |model| model.persisted? }
```